# C string allocation

Tags: c

Hey I would like to make some review of my old knowledge of C language usage. I would like to allocate memory for C string and then write to this buffer or read from this buffer C string. What I remember there is something like '\0' at the end of each character array to denote C-string.

So is it correct to always allocate string as (STRLEN + 1) and do the same while reading or writing (to file, socket, etc.).

```
char *myCString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(STRLEN+1)) 
read(fd, buff, STRLEN+1); 
write(fd, buff, STRLEN+1);
```

Thanks for clarification this issue.

Comment: the `\0` is called a NULL terminator which indicate the end of the string.

Comment: The answer is more or less "yes". But here we cannot know what exacly `STRLEN` is. And it also depends on the format of your file. The question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, that's right, a `'\0'`-terminated character array is called a string in C. Also, `sizeof (char)` is always 1 so that's kind of pointless. And `myCString` and `buff` are not the same but perhaps those two weren't supposed to be related.

Comment: I mean STRLEN to be string length as also return by strlen(cstring) call. I think it is obvious. It is capitalized as I consider it to be a constant size of buffer. '\0' character for me seems extra +1 character rather than regular string character that are included in STRLEN.

Answer (score 1):

You are more-or-less correct.  My notes on this code

```
char *myCString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(STRLEN+1))
```

This does indeed allocate a buffer of STRLEN+1 bytes (if sizeof(char) is one byte).  STRLEN should probably be the maximum number of bytes that you are expecting to read.  The compiler will probably complain because malloc returns a void* type, and you are storing it in a char*.  Add a (char*) typecast to the malloc call.

```
read(fd, buff, STRLEN+1);
```

This will read a maximum of (STRLEN+1) bytes into the buffer called 'buff' from the file handle fd.  Apart from the fact that you have called the buffer 'myCString', this is Ok. However, this read does not add a '\0' to the end of the characters read from the file, and it will not stop at the end of a line.

If you are trying to read and write lines, then I propose that you read about fopen/fclose/fprintf/fputs/fscanf/fgets.  These are the traditional C library functions for performing string IO to a file.

```
write(fd, buff, STRLEN+1);
```

This will write (STRLEN+1) bytes to the file, no matter what the length of the string is in the buffer.

For instance, suppose STRLEN=7 (so you have an 8 character buffer).  And let's suppose that you have the word 'HELLO' in the buffer.

The memory will be:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
H  E  L  L  O  \0 ?? ??
```

The ?? denotes that this memory may have any value.

If I do 'write(fd, buf, 8)', then it will write all 8 bytes to the file. The file will end up with:

```
H E L L O \0 ?? ??
```

I expect that you would rather have 5 bytes in the file (H E L L O)

As an example of reading, lets say you have a file with 2 lines in it, with unix file endings.   It might look like:

```
H E L L O \n W O R L D \n
```

(where \n = the new line character)

Notice that there are no \0 characters in the file.  \0 as a buffer terminator is a C thing, and has no analogue in a file.

If I did 'read(fd, buf, 8) then my buffer would end up with:

```
H E L L O \n W O
```

8 characters are read, and the string has no '\0'  on the end.  If I were to try to print it then I would get a failure because there is no \0.

The correct functions are fgets and fputs, which will read and write strings, taking into account \n.